# Fraction scaling not working in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution

I recently installed ubuntu 18.04 along with windows 10. The installation was done into an SSD which contained the Windows OS, but of course, partitioned. So, the Windows OS is in one partition and the Linux in other. Anyways, I am using an external monitor and everything (icons, font size) looks tiny. I came across the fractional scaling solution -

`gsettings set org.gnome.mutter experimental-features "['scale-monitor-framebuffer']"`

but this isn't working for me. I don't see the fractional scaling option in my settings. (For info: I tried both Wayland and Xorg commands for fractional scaling). I also tried scaling the font size but it just doesn't look good.

Since this doesn't work I want to know if there is an alternative solution or should I reinstall the OS?

Thanks

Comment: You need to separate these into separate question posts: a single question dedicated to a single problem.

Comment: Okay, I will. Thanks